# Cannot delete into trash

Tags: linux, filesystems, kali-linux, nautilus

I'm unable to delete anything into **trash** in my Kali Linux system. I can only permanently delete items. When I try deleting, I keep getting the message:

> **file/folder** can't be put in the trash. Do you want to delete it permanently?
>
> Unable to find or create trash directory for /path/to/file/or/dir/file

Why can't I delete into trash?

Below is my **fstab**:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
#Entry for /dev/sda5 :
UUID=92dcad4f-3256-4908-b299-90edc8bd5dbf   /   ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1
#Entry for /dev/sda3 :
UUID=08BDB5EF06C52B43   /media/rev/08BDB5EF06C52B43 ntfs-3g defaults,nodev,nosuid,locale=en_US.UTF-8    0   0
#Entry for /dev/sda4 :
UUID=5431214957EBF5D7   /media/rev/5431214957EBF5D7 ntfs-3g defaults,nodev,nosuid,locale=en_US.UTF-8    0   0
#Entry for /dev/sda1 :
UUID=63CA6D5A72F6F4CF   /media/rev/63CA6D5A72F6F4CF ntfs-3g defaults,nodev,nosuid,locale=en_US.UTF-8    0   0
#Entry for /dev/sda6 :
UUID=e6a455d8-8459-434b-aa0c-813ce9335041   none    swap    sw  0   0
/dev/sr0     /media/cdrom0    udf,iso9660   user,noauto     0   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to have it somewhere else to copy it:

First, confirm that your normal user is ID "1000":

```
id
```

Then

```
 sudo mkdir -p /.Trash-1000/{expunged,files,info}  

 sudo chown -R $USER /.Trash-1000
```

Check Here

https://askubuntu.com/questions/262817/unable-to-find-or-create-trash-directory

Answer (score 1):

```
su
rev@kali-rev:~$ chown -R rev:rev /home/rev/.local/share/Trash
```